# how to get week number for a date based on month from the date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a date column in a table and I want to get week number for that particular date based on the month from that date irrespective of the day

For example:

```
01-dec-2012 to 07-dec-2012 should give week number as 1
08-dec-2012 to 14-dec-2012 should give week number as 2
15-dec-2012 to 21-dec-2012 should give week number as 3
22-dec-2012 to 28-dec-2012 should give week number as 4
29-dec-2012 to 31-dec-2012 should give week number as 5
```

This week number is not dependent on the starting day of the week i.e, it can be any day

How can I write a `select` statement to get this output in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DAY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ms176052.aspx)

```
select ((day(DateColumn)-1) / 7) + 1
from YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09763/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  D datetime
)

insert into YourTable 
select getdate()+Number
from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and
      Number between 1 and 15
```

**Query 1**:

```
select D,
       ((day(D)-1) / 7) + 1 as W
from YourTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09763/2/0)**:

```
|                              D | W |
--------------------------------------
| January, 03 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 1 |
| January, 04 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 1 |
| January, 05 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 1 |
| January, 06 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 1 |
| January, 07 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 1 |
| January, 08 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 09 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 10 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 11 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 12 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 13 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 14 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 2 |
| January, 15 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 3 |
| January, 16 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 3 |
| January, 17 2013 07:48:54+0000 | 3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

[Several options](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/fa397ba3-db13-492c-a8a8-3d8d2bb9d46a) here to do what you wish. Most promising of which seems to be use of the `DATEPART` function. But do beware that results may differ depending on your local settings.

Hope one of them works out for you.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon. What if the link goes dead? How will your answer be useful?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 declare @dates datetime
 select @dates='2012-12-22'
 SELECT datepart(dd,@dates), ceiling (cast(datepart(dd,@dates)as numeric(38,8))/7)
```